# What happens when you try to uninstall a package that doesn't exist in your project?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

Rather than typing `npm run lint` I accidentally wrote `npm un lint`. I understand that `un` is a synonym for `uninstall`, but no package `lint` ever existed in our `package.json`.

The command line says it's added 5 packages and removed 13. The `package.json` hasn't changed though, and as far as I can tell neither has `package-lock.json`.

Running 'npm list | grep lint' only shows eslint, and lint-staged, both of which I believe are still installed.

Running `npm i` doesn't install anything new.

How do I find out what happened, and what packages were added/removed?

Comment: It's an alias for https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall - you should be able to see what's changed if you diff the `package-lock.json`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm aware of that, but I don't have that package installed. The package-lock.json file is in our git repo, and it's not showing as changed in vscode. I can dig further though.

Comment: Was [`lint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint) a dependency of some other package - it has 31 dependents listed? Or are you certain that it _"doesn't exist in your project"_? Perhaps adding your _package.json_ to your question may increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @RobC I am not on the same network at the package.json, but there's nothing there I can see from that dependents list.

Comment: That _dependents list_ doesn't conclude that it wasn't in your complete dependency tree though.

Comment: @RobC I've checked my dependency list for 'lint', it's not in there. The question in the title still stands though

Comment: @Pureferret - and you checked that when, _before_ or _after_ running `npm un lint`?

Comment: @RobC after, but wouldn't that show what each package.json lists as it requiring, not what is currently installed? Also, if it was required, wouldn't me running 'npm install' have re-added it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217959/discussion-between-robc-and-pureferret).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 scopes, namely *global* and *local*. usually, the execution of `npm` turns to the local and then turn to the global.

in your case, the `npm un` did not follow any local scope options, such as `--save`, so you probably operated on the global scope.

that is why you do not see any changes to the package-lock.json

Comment: [npm un](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall) requires the `[--global|-g]` option to uninstall a package from the context of the global scope. So what makes you think that they _"probably operated on the global scope."_?